# plotting Sum of the double series?

Tags: math, plot, matlab, series

How should I plot this Double Series:

[image]

Comment: @hasanghaorian: you should edit your question, place the code you've tried, along with any errors you've encountered..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we would like to use MATLAB symbolic toolbox. I wrote a function:

```
function p = myplot(a,b)
    syms x y m n
    w = (-1)^(1/2*m+1/2*n-1)*sin(m*pi*x/a)*sin(n*pi*y/b)/(m^2/a^2+n^2/b^2)^2;
    s1 = symsum(w,n,1,10);
    s2 = symsum(s1,m,1,10);
    ezsurf(x,y,s2);
end
```